# Difference in process_time and reality

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, process

I am measuring the processing time for a function, but the results that are printed are not correct. In reality, the time is way less (approx 5 hours), but the output suggests it is taking 15 hours. From the documentation of process_time, it should print fractional seconds.

```
import time

start = time.process_time()
main() #function to calculate the elapsed time
print ("time took: ")
print(time.process_time() - start)
```

Can someone please suggest what could be wrong here? Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried using `time.time()` instead of `time.process_time()`? I mean, supposedly it is not quite as accurate but it sure is better than a result that's wrong by 5 hours... right?

Comment: First, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time), `time.process_time()` returns the sum of system CPU time and user CPU time. Furthermore, as the docs also state that it is process-wide by definition, and there exists `time.thread_time()`, I would assume that `time.process_time()` takes into account CPU times of multiple threads within the same process if you use multi-threading...